# SynchronizationContext and ASP.NET Web API Extensibility Points

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, asp.net-web-api, task-parallel-library

When we are dealing with some extensibility points in ASP.NET Web API, we also deal with TAP (Task-based Programming Pattern). At some points, we want to provide a continuation to an async method with `ContinueWith` and we do some stuff inside the delegate that we pass onto `ContinueWith`.

As Brad Wilson explained [here](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2012/04/tpl-and-servers-pt2.html) in depth that the SynchronizationContext is vital when we provide continuations. For me, the only place where I need to get back to the `SynchronizationContext` in ASP.NET Web API is the place where I need to play with `HttpContext.Current` (which is something that I would never do in an ASP.NET Web API application) and the place where I need to set some information for thread based such as `Thread.CurrentPrincipal`.

So the question is: Do we ever want to get back to the `SynchronizationContext` when we provide continuations in some extensibility points such as Message Handlers, Filters, Formatters, etc.?

Answer (score 2):

The answer is almost always *yes*.

That's not to say that you're always going to *use* the synchronization context, but given the nature of message handlers, filters, and formatters, you can't predict whether or not they'll require the use of the [`SynchronizationContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.synchronizationcontext.aspx) in order to access the [`HttpContextBase`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontextbase.aspx).

Even with filters, where you're passed something that gives you access to the `HttpContext` (say through an [`IActionFilter` implementation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.iactionfilter%28v=vs.98%29.aspx)), that `HttpContext` is going to ultimately look at the current [`CallContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.remoting.messaging.callcontext.aspx) on the thread to provide the information from that instance.  Because the current thread (when running async) doesn't have that information on it when you started the `Task`, those calls will fail.

That said, if you need general, unfettered access to `HttpContextBase` associated with the request, then you'll *absolutely* have to pass around the `SynchronizationContext` in order to access it.

However, if possible, you should copy the details *out* of the `HttpContextBase` that you need, and pass *that* around; if you're writing something very generalized, then this won't be possible.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I think that you mixed the question with ASP.NET MVC. Let's assume that you are not under ASP.NET Host. Then, you won't have the HttpContext. So, the extensibility points are not tightly coupled with those.

Comment: @tugberk The answer is still the same, really; if you have something that is tied to a particular context, and then want to go async, you really want to make sure to copy the values out of the context (or make sure you can gain access back *into* the context) that you'll need for processing.

Comment: the problem is that: in Web API, u don't nearly have any context. You can the context inside the variables which are carried through thread + the framework infrastructure always get u back to sync context if u look at the source code. That's why ur answer is not applicable.

Comment: @tugberk I'm not really sure what you're getting at.  Your comment is not clear.

Comment: The problem is that: in Web API, u don't nearly have any context. You are getting the context the method parameters (HttpRequestMessage, etc.) which are carried across threads + the framework infrastructure always get u back to sync context and u will see that if u look at the source code. That was the whole point of the question.